# node-mysql connectTimeout

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, coronasdk

I'm using Nodejs to write a socket server for my app (using Corona SDK), and so far so good, and I'm using node-mysql ([page for node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)), and that works too, but... if nothing happens and nothing uses the connection to the db, after 2 minutes (which is the default timeout) the connection closes, while I need it to remain always open as long as the scrip process is still running, can I simply set the timeout attribute of the connection to 0, and that will keep it always open, or do I need to set it for a really long time, like 24 hours (in millisecond) in order to keep it up at all times (I'm putting 24 hours since our server restarts once a day anyway).

Thanks!

Comment: I might be making a mistake, thinking "connectTimeout" is for the idle time the connection is on before it closes it self, and maybe "connectTimeout" is actually for the time out a query sent through my connection... and in that case, why does my connection closes at about 2 minutes after I create it unless I send something through it, and how to change this to make my connection always on??

Comment: No @Yuval,  it's not related to the time taken by a query. See this issue [here](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/pull/726), when this option was included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it would seem the problem was the mysql server wait_timout, which was set to 300 seconds (5 minutes), and it was what disconnected my script. seeing as I don't really want to change that variable since not only my script uses that DB, for the time being I'm simply executing a light query with a setInterval every 4 minutes, hoping this will keep my connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your MySQL server always running, you have to set the `connectTimeout` option to `0`. See the the commit ["Default connectTimeout to 2 minutes"](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/commit/5003ce7dcb267353bada42cd1020185023e27683). `0` was the default option before.

Comment: My problem with the comments on the page you linked is that all they say is that connectTimeout is relevant only to the actual initial connection to the DB, meaning if I try to connect, and things run slow, if after 2 minutes a connection is not established, it will time out, on the contrary to what I see my connection do, which is connect right up with no problem, but still after 2 minutes of inactivity, it closes, thats what happens when documentation say one thing and real life do another, I'll test this and mark your answer green if it works well.

Comment: @Yuval, you're totally right about how the `connectTimeout` option should work. Given my poor english, I had understood that it was responsible for controlling the idle time of an oppened connection, which is not right. I use this module since a long time, and as I'm used to always `end` the connection after doing some database access, I never felt the need to change this option.

I've created a scenario where I establish a connection and leave it idle, but even letting the `connectionTimeout` with the default value `2`, the connection wasn't closed automatically after 2 minutes.

Comment: What I've found is that MySQL can be configured to kill idle connnections after some time. The two MySQL server variables are [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout). The default value for both is `28800`. What you can do to check if this is what is closing your connection automatically is to set this variables to a lesser value, like `30` and see if your connection closes after this time.

Comment: yeah, it's a good idea, I will try and find out the mysql server timeouts and see if I can change those, maybe that is what closes my connection and my connection configuration, thanks, I'll keep you updated!

Comment: Well, our servers interactive_timeout is set to 28800, which is 8 hours, all is well, yet the wait_timeout is set to 300, which is 5 minuts, and it seems that that is the time frame the connection closes, I should probably play with that one and see what happens.